# Read uploaded image files with NodeJS as backend also Angular as Frontend

Tags: node.js, angular

it was my first time implementing data upload (jpeg files) on nodeserver.

let say i use this RESTapi to store uploaded data.

`http://localhost:3000/uploads/`

when i was serving my app in localhost (with `ng serve` command), it works fine. but i got confused while i try to build the project. i mean i store the files on nodejs directory but my angular only read files on it's `dist` folder.
i just realizing that both nodejs app and angular app has different directory.

my question is, is it right syntax to do this all? should i made http call to read the desired files or should i change upload path to go to my angular assets path?

Comment: You could technically upload to your asset path, however, how would your app know what files are there in the first place? I assume you also need some server side logic (or a db) to allow for an API that Angular can use to find out what images are there? Bottom line is, it doesn't really matter where they are stored in your final solution.

Comment: if it would work under the API call, it must reflex on the frontend as well.
consider this one as an answer to your question

Comment: thank you guys, it just gave me some insight about how server works ... thanks :)